# How to format request for github api

Tags: rest, url, github-api, url-parameters

I'm having trouble formatting my request for the github api.
I have tried looking at the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) and doing:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/commits/master?since=2019-01-01&until=2019-12-30
```

But this only returns one result instead of all commits for the year. I am using the requests library in python, and have also tried it natively in the browser.
Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [Single Commit API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit) with `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:ref`

You need [List commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) : `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits` :

https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/commits?since=2019-01-01&until=2019-12-30&sha=master

You can specify the branch with `sha` param. If you want the default branch, you can omit this field:

https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/commits?since=2019-01-01&until=2019-12-30